# Looking for canonical dup about choosing include directories in C/C++ for relative '#include <foo/bar.h>'

Tags: discussion, canonical

In my favorite tags ([cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmake)) I regularly see questions with the core problem like

> I have specified include directory `/some/dir/include/foo`, which contains the header `bar.h`, but compiler cannot resolve `#include <foo/bar.h>`.

(Not that every question is actually written in such simple form. Usually this information can be guessed after a few rounds in the comments.)

I don't think that such questions should be closed as "too broad"/"typo" as a very basic problem. Because aspects of relative paths in `#include` directive are rarely covered in tutorials.

It could be simpler to comment/answer

> Instead, specify include directory `/some/dir/include`

but it will carry no information for learning.

Detailed answers could require 1-2 paragraphs (plus another 1-2 paragraphs for adapt general solution for the problem in the specific question), but I would really prefer to connect all such questions to the same target.

**What question** could be used as a **dup target** for such sort of problems about #include?

Searching for the error message gives [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919081/gcc-g-no-such-file-or-directory). It has highly-upvoted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12919082/3440745) which describes many aspects of headers searching procedure, but doesn't cover relative paths.

I could add another answer for that canonical question, but I wonder what others do when process such sort of questions, which, I am pretty sure, exist outside of my favorite tags.

Comment: In what way does the answer you linked not cover what you call "relative paths"? The answer covers includes like `#include <foo.h>`. Is it that the answer does not cover `#include <foo/bar.h>` that is the problem?

Comment: 2c from outside: You could create such a QA pair yourself (self-answer). I'd make triply sure there's no better target first though.

Comment: @ShaneBishop: Yes, the problem is that linked answer doesn't cover `#include <foo/bar.h>`, which requires include directory different than one for `#include <bar.h>`.

Comment: @c-x-berger: Yes, separate QA is also an option. The advantage of the existed question is that it is **easily searchable** (by the error message). Separate QA could have a title like "Include directory doesn't work", but I found that almost none of the questions about such problem expresses that problem with such words.

Comment: Yes, this [is not easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69573283/warning-this-python-interpreter-is-in-a-conda-environment-but-the-environment?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment122982054_69573283).